# How to copy dependencies from build.gradle into sbt

Tags: scala, gradle, sbt

I am working on a scala project that uses a existing java project developed using Spring. 
My Scala project includes jars of the java project developed using Spring and loads beans from the project's application context files.
When i do so i get numerous exceptions dealing with the absence of dependent jars of the spring project. For example it uses guava or apache libs.

I understand i need to download the dependent jars of the original spring project i am trying to use. 
Now that project uses gradle. While i am using SBT. One option is to include all the jars manually in my SBT .

Is there a way to include the dependencies in the gradle build into the SBT without me having to manually go through the build.gradle and enter corresponding entries in the SBT ?

Comment: Please elaborate a little bit on what exactly do you mean by "scala project uses an existing java project".

Comment: updated with elaboration.